# Completely Stuck with Apt-Get (nothing will install)

Tags: installation, apt, updates

I have been a testing 13.04 the new Ubuntu desktop and love it. Before now I have only ever had minor errors but today I tried to install the SDK from ubuntu.

I followed the 2 steps (installing from Terminal) and I got the following error:

```
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 qtmultimedia5-dev : Hängt ab von: libqt5multimediaquick-p5 (= 5.0.1-0ubuntu1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt-get -f install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

which translates to

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: qtmultimedia5-dev: Depends: libqt5multimediaquick-p5 (= 5.0.1-0ubuntu1) but it should not be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get-f install. "Without specifying a package (or specify a solution)
```

Its in german (I live in germany but from UK) but basically its referring to a missing dependency however the dependencies wont install.

I tried the following command to fix dependencies:

sudo apt-get -f install

But got the following:

```
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von /var/cache/apt/archives/libqt5multimediaquick-p5_5.0.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 Versuch, »/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5MultimediaQuick_p.so.5.0« zu überschreiben, welches auch in Paket libqt5multimediaquick5 5.0.0-0ubuntu1~test2 ist
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqt5multimediaquick-p5_5.0.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

which translates to

```
dpkg: error processing / var/cache/apt/archives/libqt5multimediaquick-p5_5.0.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (- unpack):
      Trying to overwrite '/ usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5MultimediaQuick_p.so.5.0', which is also in package libqt5multimediaquick5 5.0.0-0ubuntu1 ~ test2
     Errors were encountered while processing:
      / var/cache/apt/archives/libqt5multimediaquick-p5_5.0.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
     E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Ever since. I cannot install or remove programs. I have tried also:

```
sudo apt-get clean (and autoclean)
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I have even tried the walkthrough on the following page:

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

I still can't get it to work! Has anyone a suggestion?

Please help me to fix aptitude.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just force overwrites on the installation of the conflictive package:

```
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libqt5multimediaquick-p5_5.0.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

If that's not enough for the installation to succeed, you can also force everything dpkg can complain about (be careful doing this!):

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libqt5multimediaquick-p5_5.0.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

After doing that, just issue the suggested command again:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```